# I cannot use the rest operator in webpack with Babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm using webpack and React for my app, and for some reason webpack is not liking `var {id, ...data} = pulse;`.

Error:

```
ERROR in ./src/main.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (122:13)

  120 |   },
  121 |   editPulse: function(pulse) {
> 122 |     var {id, ...data} = pulse;
      |              ^
  123 |     console.log('Calling editPulse API: ');
  124 |     console.log(id, data);
  125 |     console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

My `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  ...snip...
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

And through npm, my `package.json` is:

```
{
  ...snip...
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.3.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.3",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: The "rest" operator (`...`) is currently only standard for destructuring Arrays ([reference](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-destructuring-assignment)). There's a [proposal](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) to add support for it with Objects, but that's [currently "stage 3"](https://github.com/tc39/proposals#active-proposals). With Babel, you'll have to add another preset to use the operator today – [`babel-preset-stage-3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-stage-3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [@Jonathan Lonowski's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40010521/i-cannot-use-the-rest-operator-in-webpack-with-babel#comment67299251_40010521), I installed the [`babel-preset-stage-3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-stage-3) to add support to use the rest operator on Objects.

```
npm install babel-preset-stage-3 --save-dev
```

Then update the `webpack.config.js` to include that preset:

```
presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-3']
```

Answer (score 2):

Like Jonathan Lonowski said above, you'll need to npm install one of the babel-preset-stage-(0-3 here) in order to use the Rest notation/Es2015 object spread notation.

Don't forget to add the preset to your webpack.config.js file too. So if you installed the stage-2 babel preset your config file should have babel-preset-stage-2 as an additional entry under:
module: loaders: query